# Modular arithmetic three variables

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Show that if the integers $x, y,$ and $z$ satisfy $x^3 + 3y^3 = 9z^3$
then $x = y = z = 0.$
How should I interpret this question and how to proceed?
I am thinking about the Euclidean algorithm but it becomes confusing when $x,y,z$ comes like variables?

Comment: This is actually proved by infinite descent, not with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that if $d=\mbox{gcd}(x,y,z)$ then $d^3$ can be factored out of the equation.  So we can assume that $d=1$.  Then $x^3 = 9z^3-3y^3$, so $3$ divides $x$, say $ x=3k$.  So we have $3^3k^3 =  9z^3-3y^3$ and we can divide everything by $3$ to get $9k^3= 3 z^3-y^3$.  A similar argument shows $3$ divides $y$.  Repeat to show $3$ divides $z$.  This contradicts that $d=1$.

Comment: Are i testing just to divide with 3=??

Comment: Yes.  3 is the key to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The exponent of $\,3\,$ on the RHS is $\equiv 2\pmod 3\,$ but is $\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod 3$ on the LHS.